# Finding center of curvature and orientation of a noisily sampled 2D circular arc in 3D space

Tags: geometry, regression, least-squares, curvature

I have a set of noisy 3-dimensional points, sampled from a partial arc of a 2-dimensional circle (with some center and planar orientation) in 3-dimensional space. How do I find the least squares center of curvature for these points, i.e. the center of the generating circle, and the orientation of the circle's plane?

There are two variants of the problem:

1. (Potentially easier?): The position of the generating circle is not known, but a line is known that that the center of the generating circle must lie on. To further simplify, this line roughly passes through the centroid of the cloud of points. The task is to find the point on the line that is approximately equidistant from all points. (The orientation of the circle can then presumably be obtained by finding the plane that, rotated some angle about this line, results in a least-squares sum of distances from the points to the plane.)
2. Nothing is known about the center of curvature, the radius of curvature, or the orientation of the generating circle -- only the sampled points are available.

N.B. in two dimensions, I know I can use a Hough transform to find the center of curvature of circles, but Hough transforms are really finicky to get working well, and it's not obvious to me how to extend the Hough transform to three dimensions.

Comment: Why not using the 3D equation of a circle and than apply the transform as you do in 2D by minimizing the sum distances to the 3D circle?

Comment: @Moti What do you call "the" equation of a 3D circle ? Anyway, you would have to simultaneously adjust 4 parameters... I don't think it's realistic...

Comment: A first step is to be able to find the "theoretical" common plane, even if it not satisfactory, then project the points on this plane, then work in this plane by using 2D methods, in particular Hough transform you mention (which works well) or methods you will find [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Least_Squares_Circle.html)

Comment: A method of fitting in 3D which is valid not only for arc of circle  but more generally for arc of ellipse, parabola or hyperbola is explained with numerical example in this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/31477970/Regressions-et-trajectoires-3D  pp.28-34

Comment: At @Jean Marie you will not get the best results by projection into a 2D plan - some points that will be far from the "3D circle" could appear close in the projection.

Comment: A 3d circle is defined by a combination of a sphere and a plane.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, I recently found the paper that SciPy code refers to: http://www.dtcenter.org/sites/default/files/community-code/met/docs/write-ups/circle_fit.pdf  This is a big advance over some much more complex methods I found from 10 years prior.

Comment: @JJaqueline thank you, that looks like it should work.